# How to replace Login with Account on Login. [Ionic 5] -> IonicTabs

Tags: authentication, redirect, tabs, ionic5

I'm trying to replace the LoginPage with The AccountPage after user logs in, keeping the Tabs on the bottom, however after using, this.router.navigate(account), it completely removes the tabs.

Expected behaviour:
User clicks account tab, user logs in, Login page is replaced with user account page.
Below are some screenshots of the expected behaviour

[Before login](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ebBpn.png)

[After login](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3dGIk.png)

- login-page.ts

```
    login() {
        if (this.loginForm.valid) {
            this.loadingService.show();
            this.userService.login(this.loginForm.value).subscribe(
                (data: any) => {
                    this.loadingService.hide();
                    if (data.status === "success") {
                        let user = data.data;
                        this.storageService.setUser(user);
                        this.events.publish("user:logged", user);
                        this.openUserAccount(user.id, user);
                    } else {
                        this.alertService.present(data.message, data.status);
                        console.log(data.message, data.status )
                    }
                },
                () => {
                    this.loadingService.hide();
                    this.toastService.showGenericError();
                }
            );
        }
    }

    openUserAccount(id: string, user: User){
        this.dataService.setData(id, user);
        this.router.navigate(["/account", id]);


    }
```

- tabs.page.ts

```
tabs: any[] = [
        {
            name: "novelties",
            icon: "icon-novelties"
        },
        { 
            name: "pratos",
            icon: "icon-menus" },
        { 
            name: "account",
            icon: "icon-user" 
        },
        {
            name: "stores",
            icon: "icon-stores"
        },
        { 
            name: "about",
            icon: "icon-qrcode" 
        }
    ];
```

- tabs-routing.module.ts

```
const routes: Routes = [
    {
        path: "tabs",
        component: TabsPage,
        children: [
            {
                path: "novelties",
                children: [
                    {
                        path: "",
                        loadChildren: () => import("@pages/novelties/novelties.module").then(m => m.NoveltiesPageModule)
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                path: "pratos",
                children: [
                    {
                        path: "",
                        loadChildren: () => import("@pages/pratos/pratos.module").then(m => m.PratosPageModule)
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                path: "account",
                children: [
                    {
                        path: "",
                        loadChildren: () => import("@pages/login/login.module").then(m => m.LoginPageModule)
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                path: "stores",
                children: [
                    {
                        path: "",
                        loadChildren: () => import("@pages/stores/stores.module").then(m => m.StoresPageModule)
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                path: "about",
                children: [
                    {
                        path: "",
                        loadChildren: () => import("@pages/about/about.module").then(m => m.AboutPageModule)
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                path: "",
                redirectTo: "/tabs/novelties",
                pathMatch: "full"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        path: "",
        redirectTo: "/tabs/novelties",
        pathMatch: "full"
    }
];
```

Comment: You can make 2 components , one for login and one for account after login.. and in the html of tab3 you add a did with id, and in ts you write if there user have no login then getelementbyid of div.innertHTML = logincompoent else div.innerHTML =accountcomponent.. thats the main point. But if you want same page to change elements then you need to declare 2 ion-content on page and use ngIf for each ion-content, the first for view of login which will apear is storage have no login details and the second will appear if the user have login details in storage.

Comment: @MostafaHarb that's a terrible way to do it and would bring more problems. I have a service data resolver that nullifies the need for *ngIf. However, I managed to do it, the problem now is passing the data

Comment: Its terible i know but fast solution lol.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I managed to get it to work. Now I just need to be able to pass the id, which is not working.

Here's how I did it:

- tabs-routing.module.ts

```
//----- ADDED THIS PATH
{
                path: "login/account/:id",
                children: [
                    {
                        path: "",
                        loadChildren: () => import("@pages/account/account.module").then(m => m.AccountPageModule)
                    }
                ]
            },
```

- login.page.ts

```
 openUserAccount(id: string, user: User){
        this.dataService.setData(id, user);
       ///// this.router.navigate(["/account", id]); <-- REMOVED THIS LINE
        this.router.navigate(['tabs/login/account', id]); <-- REPLACED WITH 
    }
```

Now the problem with the tab is solved, however I cannot access the id.

- account.page.ts

```
    ngOnInit() {
    console.log(this.route.snapshot.parent.data["user"]); <-- I'm certain the problem is here..
        if (this.route.snapshot.parent.data["user"]) {
            this.user = this.route.snapshot.data["user"];
            console.log(this.user);
    }
    console.log(this.user);
    }
}
```

How can i acess the id

Comment: in the path you added , login/account, add to it /:id do it becomes login/account/:id and by that it should accept the route

Answer (score 0):

Ok found the solution:

- account.page.ts

```
// -----------BEFORE

    ngOnInit() {
    console.log(this.route.snapshot.parent.data["user"]); <-- I'm certain the problem       is here..
        if (this.route.snapshot.parent.data["user"]) {
            this.user = this.route.snapshot.data["user"];
            console.log(this.user);
    }
    console.log(this.user);
    }
}


// -----------AFTER

    ngOnInit() {
    this.id = this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get("id");
        this.user = this.dataService.getData( this.id);

    console.log(    this.user);
    }
```

Everything works now.